# Bootstrap thumbnail grid not starting a new row correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid of thumbnails oin my rails app but I am having trouble getting bootstrap to display the grid correctly! As you can see below however it is not starting a new row correctly! not sure what to do here. I've included my HTML below and as far as I can see it conforms with the bootstrap examples.

```
<div id="image-grid" class="col-lg-10">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/1"> 
<img alt="Img 0259" src="/system/images/images/000/000/001/thumb/IMG_0259.JPG?1369368826">
2013-05-24
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/3"> 
<img alt="Img 0034" src="/system/images/images/000/000/003/thumb/IMG_0034.JPG?1369649370">
2013-05-27
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/2"> 
<img alt="Img 0008" src="/system/images/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_0008.jpg?1369649198">
2013-05-27
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/4"> 
<img alt="Rsz 1971061 10153145204760484 336557482 n" src="/system/images/images/000/000/004/thumb/rsz_1971061_10153145204760484_336557482_n.jpg?1377656209">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/5"> 
<img alt="Digital radiograph1" src="/system/images/images/000/000/005/thumb/digital_radiograph1.jpg?1377659810">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/6"> 
<img alt="Pamo" src="/system/images/images/000/000/006/thumb/pamo.jpg?1377659876">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/7"> 
<img alt="Tooth x ray 1" src="/system/images/images/000/000/007/thumb/tooth-x-ray_1.jpg?1377659952">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>  
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/8"> 
<img alt="Fig9b" src="/system/images/images/000/000/008/thumb/fig9b.jpg?1377664192">
2013-08-28
</a></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
<a href="/images/new">Upload New Image</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: what is displayed]

Comment: The number of columns in each row (as you might know) has to add up to 12 (or whatever you have set for the number of columns in a row). Is there a reason why you have only one row class and not wrapping columns in row classes? The way you have it right now is that there are 36 columns(sm) in your single row class.

Comment: Amin thank-you, I realise that the number of columns should add up to  12 but I believe in the case of thumbnails it should overflow onto a new line in the case of there being too many on one row. I was thinkng it could be because of the differing heights of the images

Comment: So, in 2017 you must rely on JS logic to fix this then.... ok....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a height issue.

I'm solving the same thing right now, and you basically have two options if you want to ditch the extraneous row containers, and have the whole set of columns grid out in a single row responsively:

1. you can make sure that all of the elements in your grid are the same height by constraining the content with css (or by simply controlling the content that gets shoved into each element)
2. You can add a little jQuery code to your page to scan your thumbnail elements, and expand their containers to the same height as the largest element in the grid. Google around for equal height jQuery plugins—there are a bunch. One additional thing you'll need to ensure that you do as well is to trigger the plugin again on resize, as it's likely that your elements will wind up with different heights again due to the responsive behaviours allowing content to expand/contract.  A combination of bootstrap's col classes and a bit of jQuery height-balancing is working quite well for me.

Comment: Thanks!! this is now working for me :) luckily I set my thumbnail size server side the problem was coming up when they were non standard aspect ratios and orientations. So I just used a bit of CSS, if it doesnt work ill look into a javascript solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I fixed with this script pretty quickly and painless free:

```
<script>
  $.getScript('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.min.js',function(){
    $('#projects_container').isotope({
      itemSelector : '.project_item',
      layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });
  });
</script>
```

for your case, replace '#projects_container' for '#image-grid' and add a class for each item div.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe or add images to show how your grid should look (desktop, tablet and mobile). Now we have to guess.

A row with class col-md-2 colomns can contain 6 columns (6 x 2 = 12). Try the code below, with nested columns (see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

```
<div class="container">     
<div class="row">
<div id="image-grid" class="col-sm-12 col-md-10">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/1"> 
<img alt="Img 0259" src="/system/images/images/000/000/001/thumb/IMG_0259.JPG?1369368826">
2013-05-24
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/3"> 
<img alt="Img 0034" src="/system/images/images/000/000/003/thumb/IMG_0034.JPG?1369649370">
2013-05-27
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/2"> 
<img alt="Img 0008" src="/system/images/images/000/000/002/thumb/IMG_0008.jpg?1369649198">
2013-05-27
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/4"> 
<img alt="Rsz 1971061 10153145204760484 336557482 n" src="/system/images/images/000/000/004/thumb/rsz_1971061_10153145204760484_336557482_n.jpg?1377656209">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/5"> 
<img alt="Digital radiograph1" src="/system/images/images/000/000/005/thumb/digital_radiograph1.jpg?1377659810">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/6"> 
<img alt="Pamo" src="/system/images/images/000/000/006/thumb/pamo.jpg?1377659876">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/7"> 
<img alt="Tooth x ray 1" src="/system/images/images/000/000/007/thumb/tooth-x-ray_1.jpg?1377659952">
2013-08-28
</a>            </div>  
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"> 
<a class="thumbnail text-center" href="/images/8"> 
<img alt="Fig9b" src="/system/images/images/000/000/008/thumb/fig9b.jpg?1377664192">
2013-08-28
</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2"> 
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
<a href="/images/new">Upload New Image</a>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you Bass,  I know I could solve this programatically b adding a new row every 6 images, BUT this breaks the responsive nature of bootstrap, if I add a new row every 6 then it will look fine on a desktop but as you can see on a small screen I have the thumbnails with a width of 6 meaning two to a line.
I was hoping for a responsive solution

Comment: try using sm and remove md and only use sm, see if that helps. sm class kind of works like the old span classes. Not the best solution but i guess worth trying

Comment: @mattclar See the table here: https://github.com/bassjobsen/woocommerce-twitterbootstrap. I don't understand why adding a row would break responsibility. But your are right following the examples of http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed. They add b.e. 3 times xs-6 in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using different sized images in a thumbnail div using the Bootstrap3 framework. This caused the rows and grids to break apart depending on image sizes. My work around was to use a nifty little jquery plugin called "equalize" and called it on the "row" class.

This worked perfectly, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use `display: inline-block` and manually configure the responsive columns instead of using the col-X-X class of bootstrap. I wanted 3 columns for XL screens and 2 for L, and 1 for the rest. This is the CSS I used.

```
.section-card-col {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .section-card-col {
    width: calc(33% - 16px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .section-card-col {
    width: calc(50% - 16px);
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This will solve your issue

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="well">
       content goes here...
   </div>
</div>
```